# Create View is posting Null values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, I'm trying to make create an object in my view. The object consists of a full address with a client ID and first and last name. when the page first loads, the client information goes in fine, but when I post the data( hit submit) the client data disappears and becomes null which crashes the webpage.

**Here's my class**

```
public class clientAddressEdit
{
    //public Clients client {get; set;}
    public long clientID { get; set; }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }

}
```

**My model**

```
namespace VolumeV2.Models
{
    public class Address
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string City {get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Province {get; set;}

        public virtual Clients client { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My Create methods from the AddressController**

```
    //
    // GET: /Address/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(long id)
    {
        Clients client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        editor = new clientAddressEdit();
        editor.clientID = client.Id;
        editor.firstName = client.FirstName;
        editor.lastName = client.LastName;
        editor.address = new Address();
        ViewData["editor"] = editor;
        return View(editor);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Address/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(clientAddressEdit dto)
    {
        // dto is coming in with only the address and null values
        // clientId, firstName and lastName

        clientAddressEdit temp = new clientAddressEdit();
        temp = dto;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                
            //add the address to the client
            //fails here because clientId is null 
            var client = db.Clients.Find(temp.clientID);
            client.Address = temp.address;

            //save the address
            db.Address.Add(temp.address);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dto.address);
    }
```

**My Create View**
*Could there possibly be something to do with beginForm??*

```
@model VolumeV2.Models.DTOs.clientAddressEdit

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";       
}

<h2>Create Address For @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.firstName)   @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.lastName)</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Address</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.StreetAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.StreetAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.StreetAddress)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.PostalCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.PostalCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.PostalCode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.City)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address.Province)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Province)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address.Province)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Address List", "Index")
@Html.ActionLink(Model.firstName+"'s Account","../Client/Details/"+ Model.clientID,"client")


</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Any reason for ViewData["editor"] = editor;?

Comment: at this point no. i forgot to take that out

Comment: Can you add the exception that crashes the app to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model contains nulls because the values you want are not represented on the page. Try adding this to the view somewhere so the `clientID` is posted back:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.clientID)
```

Without this there is no `clientID` on the (client-side) model to sent back to the server so it results in `null`. `address` is fine because you have `EditorFor`'s for them.

Comment: Tyiar, incredible, thank you very much, i placed the hiddenfor's within the form for each value i was missing and everything is smooth sailing